# How to download automatically all newer files which are in remote ftp folder in shell script?

Tags: shell

For example i have two servers 1. Server A & 2. Server B

Server A has directory called /testdir with some files, I need a shell script which will run in Server B to download (FTP) the files from Server A /testdir. This download should happen automatically whenever a new file is added in Server A  /testdir and old files should be neglected.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using 'lftp' incremental transfer (mirror). As an alternative, 'wget' has similar mirroring functionality:

With wget:

```
wget -mirror -nH -o ftp://serverA/testdir
```

With lftp:

```
lftp
open ftp://serverA/
mirror /testdir .
```